# Paste clipboard text to the end of a URL string

Tags: vba, powershell

I have a working Word macro that inserts whatever text has been selected into a URL and then navigates to the webpage specific to the text I have selected (I am navigating to a search box on that webpage). The whole of the working macro is as follows:

```
ActiveDocument.FollowHyperlink _
    Address:="https://WEBSITE/en/", _
    ExtraInfo:="#search/id=" & Selection, _
    Method:=msoMethodGet
```

I want the same thing to work across platforms (not just when text is selected in Word): i.e., highlight any text in a Word doc, PDF, Excel doc, or webpage and perform the navigate-to-the-webpage-and-search-for-the-selected-text action. I assume I have to use a .bat to do this (which I will activate with a keystroke or task tray icon).

In my .bat, the following code works to open the webpage, and it goes to the search box, but I can't get the selected text (or clipboard contents if it comes down to that) to append to the end of the string (the part after the =):

```
Start """%ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "https://WEBSITE/en/#search/id=" & Selection
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Which version of PowerShell are you using? Sounds like you need [`Get-Clipboard`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-clipboard?view=powershell-5.1) (added in `v5.0`)

Comment: As an aside: don't explicitly invoke any particular browser. `start` knows how to handle URLs (by invoking the user's preferred browser).

Comment: With batch files you can only put things to the clipboard.  You cannot retrieve from the clipboard.  So not you are not doing this with pure batch.

Comment: (to gms0ulman): I did a get-host and it said V2.0.

Comment: (to Squashman): I was concerned about that (it looked that way from my reading).

Comment: (to Mostert): When I remove the explorer from the start command (Start "https://www.WEBPAGE/en/#search/id=") my code hangs at the DOS console and doesn't go to the webpage at all.

Answer (score 0):

For the PowerShell:

`[System.Windows.Clipboard]::GetText()`

Or you can use **paste** in case of .bat:

http://www.c3scripts.com/tutorials/msdos/paste.html

Comment: (to Batkov): I think I need the paste function, but I will now wait until we get the new version of Powershell and use the "GetText" function. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell `Start-Process` will open a URL in the default browser, and `Get-Clipboard` (PowerShell v5+ only) to retrieve clipboard contents.

```
Start-Process "https://WEBSITE/en/#search/id=$(Get-Clipboard)"
```

In the middle of a URL if you wanted:

```
Start-Process "https://WEBSITE/en/uk/$(Get-Clipboard)/id=123456&page=1"
```

Or for older versions of PowerShell:

```
Start-Process "https://WEBSITE/en/#search/id=$([System.Windows.Clipboard]::GetText())"
```

Comment: (to James): Thank you for the suggestion. I used the following code: "https://www.WEBSITE/en/#search/id=$(Get-Clipboard)". My output on the webpage was "https://www.WEBSITE/en/#search/id=$(Get-Clipboard)". So I tried "https://www.WEBSITE/en/#search/id="$(Get-Clipboard) and my output was "https://www.WEBSITE/en/#search/id=$(Get-Clipboard)". So I tried ""https://www.WEBSITE/en/#search/id=" & $(Get-Clipboard) and my output was "https://www.canlii.org/en/#search/id="

Comment: You will be using an old version of PowerShell then, see edit.

Comment: (to James): I am using v2. I think I will have to wait for our Windows 10 upgrade to implement. The "paste.exe" (or whatever it is called) is not included in my Windows 32 program files nor the machines that would implement my action. So, once that happens in 6 mos. I'll try this again. Thank you again.